glmmTMB ZINB model non-convergence
Cross-posting from StackExchange:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/645138/glmmtmb-zinb-model-non-convergence
I am looking for help with fitting a ZINB model with mixed-effects. The model which I intend to fit contains a random-intercept (three variables/terms denoting the nested, hierarchical group structure) and a random-slope (time variable with 165 time points). The issue is that the model produces an output for random-intercept model, but fails to produce an output (produces an error) for random-slope model.
I started a discussion with package author here: https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/1023
My model formula looks like this:
var9 ~ var13 + var14 + var19 + var20 + var34 + var46 + var47 + var50 + var51 + var52 + var56 + var57 + var59 + var60 + var62 + var65 + var66 + var89 + var90 + var91 + var92 + var93 + var94 + (var2 | var4/var3/var1)

He suggested specifying time variable as continuous in random-slope formula and refitting the model. It returned an output on a test dataset which is roughly 1% of the original dataset (had NA values for AIC, BIC, loglik, deviance), but failed on the full dataset.
In (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  :
  NA/NaN function evaluation
Error in ff(x, order = 1) : 
  inner newton optimization failed during gradient calculation
outer mgc:  NaN 
Error in (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL,  : 
  NA/NaN gradient evaluation
Calls: glmmTMB ... with.default -> eval -> eval -> do.call -> <Anonymous>
Timing stopped at: 5258 879.3 6540
Execution halted

Attributes of my dataset: My original dataset has 2429283 observations. var4 has 53 levels. interaction(var4, var3) has 375 levels. interaction(var4, var3, var1) has 61125 Levels.
I am currently looking at some references suggested here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/601936/glmmtmb-model-convergence-problem-non-positive-definite-hessian-matrix
Could anyone kindly advice on how to get the model to converge and obtain a valid output. I am happy to share the test dataset and any other details as needed. Thank you in advance for your help.

You've already shared your test data set, but of course it's hard to troubleshoot when (1) the full data set is large/unshareable and (2) the failure modes are different on the testing subsample and the full data set. The test subsample likely gets NA values because of a singular fit, this might be preventable by setting priors. My only practical advice is to start with a simpler model and work up to the model that can both be fitted (computationally feasible and doesn't fail to converge) and is as close as possible to what you actually want.

Thank you so much for the great advice, @BenBolker! I am currently trying to fit the model using "brms" package. I will probably be posting more questions as I get further along to seek expert guidance from the StackOverflow R community.
